Renaming "Post" to Something Else without editing functions.php
I want to extent this question.
I am using Avada builder (pre-built site) and my site is hosted in cPanel (in which I am not the admin), so I don't have access to functions.php and I can't really add plugins (without contacting the admin, which I would like to avoid).
I am not really interested in changing the name in dashboard, but I want the "breadcrumbs" element to display "announcements" instead of "posts" in the page path displayed when used.
How can I do this without editing functions.php please?
The only answers I found involve editing the functions.php.
